# Reading of char-element ignoring 0-plases (spaces) without using libraries C++

Tags: c++, pointers, char, getchar, null-pointer

How can I write an algorithm that reads a char-element until the end of the line,ignoring 0-places using pointers and using no library functions (only getchar,printf,scanf,cin and cout)?

```
char readchar () {


    char a;
    char* pointer=0;
    while(pointer!='\n') {
    a=getchar();
    std::cout<<a;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "0-places"? Do you mean spaces?

Comment: Ye,I ment spaces and '\n'

Comment: Just use `while (std::cin >> c && c != '\n') { ... }`.